# Java config instead of @ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to create Java-based configuration class that does exactly same as `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {X.class})`  ?

I have to create generic configuration class (for extending in tests) doing something like that:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = T.class)
public class EndpointTestConfig<T> {
}
```

It's impossible to use generics with annotations so I would need the same effect using Java.

Comment: Is it something like component-scan in spring ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. If I understand you correctly you have a base class T and a lot of derived classes? And you want to have a base config that will create common beans and every extender will create a bean of class that extends T? So you can do something like that:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseTestConfig {
  //common beans
}

@Configuration
@Import(BaseTestConfig.class)
public class ConcreteEndpointConfig {

  @Bean
  public YourDerivedClass bean() {
    return new YourDerivedClass();
  }
}
```

I hope that I got your idea. If this is not what you need please elaborate.